# Subsequent API calls in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I want to call two APIs , the result of the first to be the param of the second. The first API call completes and tends to render the screen and throws JS error .The results to be displayed on screen are the results of the second API call.  I want to hold the rendering until both API calls complete. I am working on Vue3 and this is my code.

```
 async function getResults(OrderNum: string ): Promise<void> {
        try {
             await api.get(`/getFilters`)
                .then(async (response1) => {
                    const resFilter = response1
                    
                     api.post(`/getResults/${OrderNum}`, resFilter).then(async (response2) => {
                        resultList.value = response2.sort(
                            (a: any, b: any) => new Date(b.created) - new Date(a.created)
                        )
                    })
                })
        } catch (err) {
           
            console.log("inside getResults catch - no records !!" + err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you see on the screen?

Comment: "_tends to render the screen and throws JS error_".  Please be more specific.  What is the error? What is being rendered?  Is it first initial render of the component, or is it a rerender? How does this code relate to the rest of your component, i.e. is it called on mounted or is it user controlled? If you're talking about delaying initial render until the API calls are done, look into [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why mix both `await` & `then`? With `then` you DON'T catch errors from the second api call since it's executed async out of the current `try` block, just use `await` everywhere:

```
 async function getResults(OrderNum: string ): Promise<void> {
        try {
             resultList.value = await api.post(`/getResults/${OrderNum}`, await api.get(`/getFilters`));
             resultList.value.sort(
                            (a: any, b: any) => new Date(b.created) - new Date(a.created)
                        );
        } catch (err) {
           
            console.log("inside getResults catch - no records !!" + err)
        }
    }
```